# Where Can i find animated volume bar in css

Tags: css, animation, web

After searching a lot on internet I can't find a way to get an animated volume bars like this website : https://my.pottermore.com/patronus

If anyone know how to create a button like this please let me know bellow.
I tried much times but nothing worked properly.

This is what I've done so far :

```
jsfiddle.net/dzk6uj7e/74/
```

Best regards,

Comment: care to start the js fiddle? It would be nice to see code. The thing is, I'm not sure this is a question for CSS. But rather JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Comment: view the page source, or inspect the element, the code is right there

Comment: While @Aloso did anyway, Stack Overflow is not meant to be a code-writing service. We're here to help out when you have a stumbling block or need help on a particular piece of doing it yourself.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry I didn't post the code because it was on the website files quoted upstair. I also tried to copy the elements which interested me but nothing working well. Appears that something is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button consists of 8 lines which are html elements that are 1px tall or wide. It's not that difficult:

```css
body {
  background-color: #444444;
}

.fancybutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.v1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: -35px 0;
}
.v2 {
  left: 5px;
  top: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0;
}
.v3 {
  right: 5px;
  top: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0;
}
.v4 {
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: -35px 0;
}

.h1 {
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 -95px;
}
.h2 {
  left: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 -100px;
}
.h3 {
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 -100px;
}
.h4 {
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 -95px;
}


.buttontext {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
}

.fancybutton:hover .buttontext {
  background-color: white;
  color: #222222;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.fancybutton:hover .v1, .fancybutton:hover .v4 {
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fancybutton:hover .v2, .fancybutton:hover .v3 {
  height: 70px;
  margin: -35px 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fancybutton:hover .h1, .fancybutton:hover .h4 {
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fancybutton:hover .h2, .fancybutton:hover .h3 {
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 -95px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancybutton">
  <div class="line vertical v1"></div>
  <div class="line vertical v2"></div>
  <div class="line vertical v3"></div>
  <div class="line vertical v4"></div>

  <div class="line horizontal h1"></div>
  <div class="line horizontal h2"></div>
  <div class="line horizontal h3"></div>
  <div class="line horizontal h4"></div>

  <div class="buttontext">FANCY BUTTON</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However I was interested in an another button. That was the volume button at the bottom right of the page ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dzk6uj7e/94/ Here it's working :)

Comment: Thanks for your interest man, very appreciated. I found a way 2 days ago. However, the text translation is still not working ;)